# NSPredicate to return Items with properties contained in arrays

Tags: core-data

I have an array of year/months tuples:

`[(2015, 11), (2015, 12), (2016, 1), (2016, 2), (2016, 3), (2016, 4), (2016, 5), (2016, 6), (2016, 7), (2016, 8), (2016, 9)]`

In my CoreData ManagedObjectModel, I have a MonthlyReport entity that has `year` and `month` properties (Int16)

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to fetch all models which year and month properties match the tuples from the array.

I tried the following (with `uniqueYears` and `uniqueMonths` arrays of unique values):

```
let predicateYear = NSPredicate(format: "$name in $NAME_LIST", "year", uniqueYears)
let predicateMonths = NSPredicate(format: "$name in $NAME_LIST", "month", uniqueMonths)

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EntityName")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicateYear, predicateMonths])
```

but that doesn't work; the app crashes with the message `unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : ($name IN $NAME_LIST)'`

Right now, I'm stuck with fetching then manually filtering all models, which is far from efficient.

Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an easy way to do this.  You will need to build a fairly complex predicate to find the combinations.  Something like this:

```
var predicate: NSPredicate
for tuple in incomingTuples {
  let singlePredicate = NSPredicate("year == %@ AND $month == %@", tuple.0, tuple.1)
  if predicate == nil { 
    predicate = singlePredicate 
  } else {
    predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate, singlePredicate])
  }
}
```

I suspect that this is going to be an expensive SQL query.

Comment: Do you mean `orPredicateWithSubpredicates`?